# excel sum the values of column B in all rows with column A numerical value not ending with 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Let's say I have a table like this (price is column A, qty is column B)

I would like to sum the values of qty in rows with price not ending with 0.

In this case, would like to know what formula can give me a number 350 (250 + 100) (as prices 44.0313 and 44.0399 are not ending with 0).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try `MOD()` Function,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **A9**

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--RIGHT(TEXT(MOD($A$2:$A$7,1),"#.0000"))<>0)*($B$2:$B$7))
```

[image: EXPLANATION]

**Each Formula Break Down**

• Formula used in cell **D2** --> *Extracts the decimal part*,

```
=MOD(A2:A7,1)
```

• Formula used in cell **E2** --> *Converts To Text*,

```
=TEXT(D2:D7,"#.0000")
```

• Formula used in cell **F2** --> *Extracts the last character*,

```
=RIGHT(E2:E7)
```

• Formula used in cell **G2** --> `BOOLEAN LOGIC`,

```
=--F2:F7<>0
```

• Formula used in cell **H2** --> *An array of TRUE's & FALS's multiplies with the corresponding values*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(G2:G7*B2:B7)
```

Comment: @JvdV Sir, used it because `MOD()` returns the decimal number after division by 1, the fractional part of the whole number. Sir, your kind advise is expected !

Comment: @JvdV Sir, but `MOD()` exclusively get the number after dot. So if there is no zero also at last it can get it may be I am wrong

Comment: @JvdV Sir, you are correct but what if there are **5** digits after the dot

Comment: @JvdV Sir, agreed sir, with you, should I then remove the solution then as you say Sir!

Comment: No, don't remove a working solution. I also credited you. The comment is just that `MOD()` does not do anything extra here and can be removed=)

Comment: @JvdV Sir, alright, but may be someone finds it useful in other ways. So that it can be developed more for more complex scenarios !

Answer (score -1):

Try [sumproduct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(A1:A4,1)<>"0")*(B1:B4))
```

[image]

Comment: OP's values are numbers by the looks of it, not text. Maybe try `=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(TEXT(A1:A4,"#.0000"))<>"0")*(B1:B4))` instead.

Comment: i agree with your answer - even though excel is showing 44.210 sometime, the actual value of it is still 44.21, also counting it as non-0 ending.